# Remove lines from text file

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit, regexp-replace

I have a text file from which I want to exclude lines which start with the number 1 to 9. I tried to replace them with blank (empty string) using regular expressions `^\d+(.*)$` and `^[1-9](.*)$`, but it doesn't work.

I am using AutoIt's [`StringRegExpReplace()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExpReplace.htm) command.

Comment: It's working in notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchors `^` and `$` match at the beggining and end of **string** by default.

To make them match at the beggining and end of **line**, you have to set the `MULTILINE (?m)` modifier.

```
(?m)^\d.*$
```

Comment: @dustmouse some functions, like AutoIt's [`StringRegExpReplace()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExpReplace.htm) don't have a parameter for modifiers, That's why you need to use [inline modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). Though they're still useful in some other cases (e.g. only make a part of your pattern case-insensitive).